# Assign json stored in a file to a js variable

Tags: javascript, json, protovis

I am working on a project and I was not able to figure out how to do this. I have a json file and need to assign it to a js variable to use the protovis visualization tools.

I tried searching on google but could not find any. Please let me know if someone knew how to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [jQuery's parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/).

> Description: Takes a well-formed JSON string and returns the resulting
>   JavaScript object. version added: 1.4.1jQuery.parseJSON( json )
>   jsonThe JSON string to parse. Passing in a malformed JSON string may
>   result in an exception being thrown.

Comment: jQuery is open-source, go rip out the part you need.

Comment: Thanks,Can you also help me how to read the file which is stored locally ?

Comment: Browsers cannot read local files (HTML5 local storage is a different issue) . If they could web pages would be poking around your hard drive without authorization.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting the file from your server via the XMLHttpRequest object, you can parse the json using the JSON.parse function:

```
var myJson = JSON.parse(response);
```

For browsers that don't support the JSON object you can get a library for it here: http://www.json.org/js.html

Comment: Actually I'm not getting the file from the server, its stored locally. Do you know how I can access files stored locally ?

Comment: Diodeus response to this issue above is correct. If you're aiming for HTML5 enabled browsers, do a Google search and you'll find the API. Additionally, the answers here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript - might also interest you.